# How to filter query SPARQL for property "type"

Tags: sparql

I have a data source file that one of its properties is an actual class instance:

```
<clinic:Radiology rdf:ID="rad1234">
        <clinic:diagnosis>Stage 4</clinic:diagnosis>
        <clinic:ProvidedBy rdf:resource="#MountSinai"/>
        <clinic:ReceivedBy rdf:resource="#JohnSmith"/>
        <clinic:patientId>7890123</clinic:patientId>
        <clinic:radiologyDate>01-01-2017</clinic:radiologyDate>
  </clinic:Radiology>
```

so `clinic:ProvidedBy` is pointing to this:

```
<clinic:Radiologists rdf:ID="MountSinai">
        <clinic:name>Mount Sinai</clinic:name>
        <clinic:npi>1234567</clinic:npi>
        <clinic:specialty>Oncology</clinic:specialty>
 </clinic:Radiologists>
```

How do I query using the property `clinic:providedBy` (which is of type `clinic:Radiologists`)?  Whatever I have tried does not bring back results.

Comment: Please show the query that you tried so far.

Comment: And why is a property `providedBy` of type `Radiologists`? - at least that's what you wrote in the text.

Comment: I have just tried basic queries that did not work, here's an example:
SELECT *
WHERE { ?x rdf:resource "#MountSinai" }

It's off that type cause it is a property that pointing to a different object.

Comment: That is not a SPARQL query. RDF is made of triples, thus, SPARQL is made of triple patterns. And a resource is identified by a URI, not a string literla. I'm wondering whether you read any RDF and SPARQL tutorial.

Comment: Well I am basing it on this tutorial:
http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_query1.html

Comment: and other queries using String literals do work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's also not clear what exactly you want to have, so my answer will return *"all radiology resources that are provided by MountSinai"*:

```sql
PREFIX clinic: <THE NAMESPACE OF_THE_CLINIC_PREFIX>
PREFIX : <THE_BASE_NAMESPACE_OF_YOUR_RDF_DOCUMENT>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {
  ?s clinic:ProvidedBy :MountSinai
}
```

But, I really suggest to start with an RDF and SPARQL tutorial, since form your comment your query

```sql
SELECT * WHERE { ?x rdf:resource "#MountSinai" }
```

is missing fundamental SPARQL basics. And for writing a matching SPARQL query it'S always good to have a look at the data in Turtle resp. N-Triples format both of which being closer to the SPARQL syntax.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know the namespace since you did not provide the beginning of the RDF document where all namspaces are defined. Cheers.